# Skype Access does not identify available hotspots

Tags: wireless, skype

Skype access is a pay as you go wifi hotspot service as part of the Skype package, which allows use of e.g. Boingo as a pay per minute service.

In Ubuntu 11.10 when running Skype Access it never finds available hotspots to use the service. NM sees the Boingo service hotspots, but Skype Access says there are no Skype Access services available. At the same locations, using the same computer but switching to the Windows XP partition Skype Access now recognises and uses Skype Access hotspots.

Any one know why Ubuntu prevents identfication of Skype Access points and if there is a way of making it work?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!